# Not able to access array with ids in another view controller in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, nsmutablearray

these is some code from my project..

```
for (index=0; index<[feed count]; index++) {

    //NSLog(@"........%@",[feed objectAtIndex:2]);
    NSString* forName=[feed objectAtIndex:index];

    NSString *nameString = [forName valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"--------%@",nameString);
    [nameArray addObject:nameString];

    NSString *idString = [forName valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"--------%@",idString);
    [idArray addObject:idString];
```

}

```
MyFriends *detailViewController = [[MyFriends alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFriends" bundle:nil];
// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
detailViewController.fbNames=nameArray;
detailViewController.fbIds=idArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

My problem is in another controller when I am accessing array with names which is `fbNames` in another class it is showing me proper names,But when I am accessing `fbIds` which is the array with Ids ...they are showing me null..

how to correct this?

here...in this class ...fbNames are working fbIds are not..

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
```

}

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [fbNames count];
```

}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

     // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text=[fbNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Provide the code where the issue occurs

Comment: As far as I know NSString doesn't have valueForKey: method. Is it a misprint or I just miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* forName=[feed objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *nameString = [forName valueForKey:@"name"];
```

I don't think `NSString` has `valueForKey:`

Comment: but it is showing me proper name in the table view...but not ids